# Generate and download a text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, download, file-generation

All my research so far suggests this can't be done, but I'm hoping someone here has some cunning ideas.

I have a form on a website which allows users to bulk upload lots of URLs to add to a list on the server. There's quite a lot of server-side processing to do on each URL, so to avoid timeouts and to display progress, I've implemented the upload using jQuery to submit the URLs one at a time using ajax.

This is all working nicely. However, part of the processing on each URL is deduplicating it against the complete list. The ajax call returns a status indicating either a successful upload or a rejection due to duplication. As the upload progresses, I tell the user how many URLs have been rejected as duplicates (along with overall progress and ETA).

The problem now is how to give the user a complete list of the failed duplicate URLs. I've kept them in an array in my jQuery, and would like the user to be able to click on a link on the form to download a text file containing those URLs. Is this possible just using client-side processing?

The server-side processing basically handles a single keyword at a time. I'd rather not have to store the duplicates in a database table with some kind of session key which gets sent with every ajax call, and is then used at the end to generate the text file server-side (and then gets cleaned up some time later). I can see how to do this, but it seems very clunky and a bit 20th century.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used it myself yet, but [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify) was built for exactly this purpose I think.

> Downloadify is a tiny JavaScript + Flash library that enables the generation and saving of files on the fly, in the browser, without server interaction.

It was created by [Doug Neiner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152083/doug-neiner) who is also pretty active on Stack Overflow.

It needs Flash 10 to work.

Comment: Doug seems to have whored out his site since you posted this... I don't see any JS library on that site.

Comment: @Mark I know Doug a little bit, I can't see him doing that... Maybe something went wrong with the registration. I'll ask him when I talk to him.

Comment: Ahh..because I was just trying to figure out how to do the same thing. Would have liked to try that lib :)

Comment: @Mark see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701618/opening-a-file-save-dialog-via-javascript-using-flash/4701639#4701639