# Opening a file save dialog via JavaScript using Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, html

I know that there is no implementation of File Save Dialog in JavaScript as of now, but it can be done with Flash. I am looking for a lib or source code in Flash that could do it for me so that I can call it via JavaScript. JavaScript knows the data and filename, I just want to open a file save dialog.

Also, would it be possible to save multiple files at once? The user may create a couple of files and save them, so, it would be nice if I need not open the dialog for each write. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doug Neiner's Downloadify is a Flash/JS library that does this.

The main domain seems gone for some reason, but here is Doug's [Github page.](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify)

[Here](http://davidwalsh.name/downloadify) is a blog post explaining the usage.

Comment: Hey, do you think I could save multiple files with this?

Comment: @rFactor I don't see why not! Try  it out. (It's probably going to be possible only one by one, though, not many files at once.)